Getting ErrorCode:AuthorizationPermissionMismatch when listing blobs from Python while AZ CLI works with the same creds
I've got an existing storage account / container where I can list all the blobs using AZ CLI:
[ ~ ]$ az storage blob list --account-name storageaccount20122022 --container-name test

There are no credentials provided in your command and environment, we will query for account key for your storage account.
It is recommended to provide --connection-string, --account-key or --sas-token in your command as credentials.

You also can add `--auth-mode login` in your command to use Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) for authorization if your login account is assigned required RBAC roles.
For more information about RBAC roles in storage, visit https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-cli.

In addition, setting the corresponding environment variables can avoid inputting credentials in your command. Please use --help to get more information about environment variable usage.
[
  {
    "container": "test",
    "content": "",
    ...
  }
]

I want to do the same from Python, this is my script:
import sys
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

def list_blobs_using_cli_credential(account_name, container_name):
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()   # Also tried AzureCliCredential()
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(
        account_url=f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net",
        credential=credential
    )
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    print(f"Listing blobs in {account_name}/{container_name} ...")
    try:
        blobs = container_client.list_blobs()
        for blob in blobs:
            print(blob.name)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error listing blobs: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    account_name = sys.argv[1]
    container_name = sys.argv[2]
    list_blobs_using_cli_credential(account_name, container_name)

However when I run that in the same shell I get an error:
[ ~ ]$ python list-blobs.py storageaccount20122022 test
Listing blobs in storageaccount20122022/test ...
Error listing blobs: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:466b2647-201e-0022-13fd-918e18000000
Time:2024-04-19T01:59:22.6413231Z
ErrorCode:AuthorizationPermissionMismatch
Content: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationPermissionMismatch</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:466b2647-201e-0022-13fd-918e18000000
Time:2024-04-19T01:59:22.6413231Z</Message></Error>

I can list the Storage accounts and the container in each account from Python but when it comes to dealing with the Blobs (list, delete, upload) I can't do anything from Python while the same ops work from AZ CLI.
I tried in two different Azure accounts, completely unrelated, in one of them I'm the owner, but it's still the same.
What is AZ CLI doing, what other permissions or roles does it automatically acquire, to do the Blob ops? And how can I do the same in my Python code?


Getting ErrorCode:AuthorizationPermissionMismatch when listing blobs from Python while AZ CLI works with the same creds.

Azure CLI commands will work with Owner access for listing blobs in a Storage account, but when using Python, it may require a specific role, such as Storage Blob Data Contributor, for the operation to succeed.
I have the Owner role at the subscription level. I'm able to list the blobs using Azure CLI, but not with Python.

Azure CLI command result

Python code result

After assigning the Storage Blob Data Contributor role, I'm able to list all blobs in the container.

Python code result after assigning role.


Thanks, that's a good start. How does AZ CLI assume the Owner access though? Can Python do something similar?

BTW Your images don't show.

You can refer this Azure Blob Storage client library for Python for listing blobs in containers and Git Hub issue for same issue.

Please change your network to a mobile hotspot or any personal network. Sometimes, corporate networks will block images from imgur.
